# how to add google appengine app to non admin users in my domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-account

I am the admin of the google account, say, mycompany.com. Employees have their email and a google account like joe@mycompany.com which give them access to docs, ... under this id.

I would like to add AppEngine as one of the apps they could use, so that every one can create one or more applications. In the dashboard where I see the list of the 7 apps they have access to( gmail, drive, ...) I don't find how to add appengine.

I can however create an appengine app under admin, but I would like to give the freedom to everyone to do it with their account. Is that possible ?

I did some research and found answers about other things. I am *not* looking to map myapp.mycompany.com to myapp.appspot.com, I managed to do that

Answer (score 0):

Using the new Admin Console home page you should:

1. Click "More Controls" which can be found towards the bottom of the screen
2. Select "Other Google Services"
3. Locate and click on "Google App Engine Admin Console"
4. Click on the drop down box under the Appengine logo and select "ON for everyone"

This should allow all users to use the Google Appengine Admin Console and create apps.